# Hide the ``\chapter{}`` with subfile in article docs, from report docs

Tags: chapters, article, report

I've got a little problem, I have to submit an assignment almost every week to our tutor, but we have to submit only one document to our prof. 
So I was thinking to use the `article` class document for my tutor, and using the `report` class for the final assignment.

I'm using the `subfile` package, so in the `main` for my tutor, I just "link" my file for the current assignment, but because I use the exact same file also to do the reportclass document for my professor, thus using `\chapter{}` at the beginning of every assignment I always get a little "title" with the chapter name, before the whole document.

So far I've found very little documentation on the `if` condition in LaTeX, can you suggest me some complete guide?? Or maybe any other solutions??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `memoir` class which is a superset of the `book`, `report`, and `article` classes.

```
% memartprob.tex  SE 539895 

\documentclass[
%  article % uncomment this to get article class output
]{memoir} % default book/report output

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Divisional title}
\section{Subsidiary title}

\end{document}
```

Enter the text using `\chapter`, etc. With the `article` class option these will be treated as `\section`, without the option they are standard chapters. (`texdoc memoir`).

Comment: Ok thanks @Peter Wilson, it's a nice option, but if I would totally get rid of the \chapter{}, are there any options? 
As I usually use the chapter name on the cover of my tutor's assignement such as a title for the whole document.

Because when I try this on the "book" cover I also get my ```\fancyhead``` and my ```\fancyfoot```, which shouldn't be on this page...